# Fun Friday: What even is a layback sound mixer anyway?

Tags: knowledge

It's Friday, it's fun, it's time to block up some of that valuable brain of yours with useless trivia.

---

[image]

---

**Text Version**

*Suggs, Chas and Lee: --- -----

George, Bill and Ronald: ----- -----

Mary-Kate, Ashley and Bob: ---- -----*

*Burdon, Price and Steel: ----- of the rising ---

Mickey and Goofy: ----- of -----*

*Boyle 2007: ---|-----

Verbinski 1997: -----|----*

*Layback sound mixer in both of these films: ----- -------*

Comment: It's fun time!!

Comment: This is a fun puzzle!

Comment: @floraline Thanks! Glad you had fun solving it. Enjoy your weekend!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Text Version

Suggs, Chas and Lee:

> OUR HOUSE

George, Bill and Ronald:

> WHITE HOUSE

Mary-Kate, Ashley and Bob:

> FULL HOUSE

Burdon, Price and Steel:

> HOUSE of the rising SUN

Mickey and Goofy:

> HOUSE of MOUSE

Boyle 2007:

> SUN|SHINE

Verbinski 1997:

> MOUSE|HUNT

Layback sound mixer in both of these films:

> LARRY HOPKINS

Comment: And that looks like game, set and match. I hate how fast you lot are sometimes. Happy Friday though!

Comment: @Bilkokuya Can you send me the puzzle 2 hours before you post here? These guys are too fast ;)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel It sometimes feels like they solve it before I even finish posting it.

Comment: Happy Friday!  Sorry about jumping on it so quick...feel like it's either fast or never.  =)   Guess I'll go back to beating my head against the Metapuzzle...  O_O

Answer (score 6):

Suggs, Chas and Lee: --- -----

> Not sure.. but it must end in 'house'

George, Bill and Ronald: ----- -----

> White house

Mary-Kate, Ashley and Bob: ---- -----

> Full house

Burdon, Price and Steel: ----- of the rising ---

> House of the rising sun

Mickey and Goofy: ----- of -----

> House of Mouse

Boyle 2007: ---|-----

> Sun|shine

Verbinski 1997: -----|----

> Mouse|hunt

Layback sound mixer in both of these films: ----- -------

> Larry Hopkins

Comment: Damn that was fast - thought this might hold up at least till the hour. Great work - just need to finish that first clue. (Looks like hagfy has just pipped you for the full-solve. But have an awesome Friday anyway!)

Comment: These guys are too fast, they leave nothing for us.

Comment: Argh...sniped!  First clue should be the one I put: uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Bhe_Ubhfr_(Znqarff_fbat)

Comment: Ahh, I see! That's the only item in this puzzle that I am not familiar with.